# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property of null errror

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS...

```
function displayMatches() {
    const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, motorcycles);
    const html = matchArray.map(bike=> {
      const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
      const bike_year = bike.year.toString().replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
      const bike_model = bike.model.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
      return`
        <li>
          <span class="name">${bike_year}, ${bike_model}, ${bike.make}</span>
        </li>
        `;
    }).join('');
    suggestions.innerHTML = html;
  }

  const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');
  const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

  searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
  searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);
```

...and am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` in the console. I tried adding a adding `window.onload = function displayMatches()`then the the error `displayMatches is not defined`.

Am I adding the onload in the right place?

Comment: The error means that `suggestions` is `null`. Are you sure that the code that declares it is running AFTER the DOM is loaded and that the element it's supposed to find actually exists?

Comment: I concur with @ScottMarcus, try to wrap your function execution of `displayMatches` in a `$(document).ready(...)` wrapper so that execution begins after the DOM is fully loaded. Also if this is not the case (we're assuming), post more code, so we can see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed when I did `console.log(suggestions)` it was null...where as searchInput returned the appropriate html. The culprit was earlier in the code in my html. I originally had...

```
<form class="search-form">
  <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for Year, Make or Model">
</form>
```

...so I added my and UL with a class of suggestions:

```
<form class="search-form">
  <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Search for Year, Make or Model">
  <ul class="suggestions"></ul>
</form>
```

Works like a charm now. Thanks!